# Is there a form of rigid body dynamics that uses unit quaternions instead of Euler angles?

Tags: classical-mechanics, simulations, rigid-body-dynamics

I’d like to know specifically about an elegant way of deriving a second derivative of an orientation quaternion from a torque and a moment of inertia matrix, if one is available.

The straight forward, but somewhat round-about way that I can think of is to solve for the derivative of the orientation of a rigid body in terms of Euler angles via classical methods. Then I would convert those angular displacement vectors into unit quaternions and continually compose the unit quaternions.

I have been trying to find a formulation for mapping net torques as a function of time to orientation quaternions as a function of time, but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: Euler angles only contain the driving parameters (3 for a free body) and quaternions are a form of homogeneous coordinates for angles with 4 parameters. I do think there has to be alternative to Euler angles (successive rotations) but I doubt quaternions are the answer.

Comment: I assume you have looked at: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) and [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)?

Comment: @honeste_vivere, that is correct, are you implying that there's something I missed there?

Comment: @SantiagoSoto - Perhaps it is I that missed something.  I thought those articles referred to rigid body rotations and translations using quaternions.